# Need dynamically inject script tag for reactJs components in pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, web-development-server

I'm building an application in ReactJS. I am adding some external CDNs. script in components. For that i am using this useEffect codes

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

const UseScript = (url) => {
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");

  script.src = url;
  script.async = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  };
}, [url]);
};

export default UseScript;
```

and here I'm using the script in this component

```js
export default function PubItems({
  id,
  title = "This is title",
  authors = "this is the author list",
  journaL = "this is the journal name",
  issue = "This is the issue number",
  date = "This is publication date",
  doi = "this is link",
  impact = "0.00",
  metric = "this is 000",
  plum = "",
}) {
  UseScript("https://badge.dimensions.ai/badge.js");
  UseScript("//cdn.plu.mx/widget-popup.js");
  return (
    <PubItemsStyles>
      <div className="pubItems_info">
        <h3>
          {
            <a className="pubtitle" href={doi} target="__blank">
              {title}
            </a>
          }
        </h3>

        <p className="authors">{authors}</p>
        <p className="journal">
          <span className="jName">{journaL}</span>
          <span className="jIssue">{issue}</span>
          <span className="jIssue">{impact}</span>
        </p>
        <p className="date">{date}</p>

        <div className="metrics">
          <div>
            {
              <a className="doi" href={doi} target="__blank">
                Read Article
              </a>
            }
          </div>

          <span>
            <a
              href={plum}
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              className="plumx-plum-print-popup plum-bigben-theme"
              data-size="medium"
              data-popup="bottom"
            >
              plumx
            </a>
          </span>

          <span
            className="__dimensions_badge_embed__"
            data-doi={metric}
            data-style="large_rectangle"
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </PubItemsStyles>
  );
}
```

The script is for the plumx and dimention span.

And it's working fine when i refresh the page. But the problem is when i'm am enter my homepage and then goes this component page this badges are not showing as the script not injecting when the homepage loaded, to show these badges a refresh needs.

**so how may i solve this problem to when i'll enter the pages the script tag will loaded automatically without refresh the page?**

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` you can add the cdn link inside the `index.html` file. the `index.html` is located in `public` folder

Comment: @kennarddh not working

Comment: Can you try to set the async attr to false